# JSP changes not refreshing -- Using RAD 8.5.1 and WebSphere 8.5

Tags: java, spring, jsp, websphere, ibm-rad

I'm having an issue with JSP's not refreshing to reflect changes I've made. My steps are, clean then build the project (Build Automatically is checked). I choose Run As and select my WASv8.5 Server to launch it. Server launches, then my EAR installs my WAR. I browse to the JSP I'm making changes to and then it doesn't update from that state. Seems like a caching issue or something, as the unzipped EAR and WAR files both show the updates JSP being correct. I'm at a loss here why this is happening. I'm not sure what to provide to help, so ask and I'll do my best to supply the needed information.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try this? In the servers view, double click your server ([reference](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRTLW_8.5.1/com.ibm.servertools.doc/topics/rwrcview.html?lang=en)) and on the editor that opens, under the **Publishing settings for WebSphere Application Server**, select **Run server with resources on Server**. Save the editor and retry your updates. _**NOTE** This wouldn't solve the problem you have, but might help narrow down the cause_

Comment: I did as you suggested and it still didn't update anything when I made changes to the JSP, still showing me the old code when I view source on the browser (Firefox and Chrome).

Comment: Check if you have in server settings `Automatically publish on resource change`. Also try `Ctrl+F5` to see if browser will refresh the view.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a caching issue. You can right click on the server, click "Add and Remove..", then remove all the deployments. Right click again, then Publish. Right click again, then clean. Restart the server and then add the EAR to it using Add and Remove. If publish changes immediately is checked, it will publish. Otherwise, right click again and click Publish.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I imagine this would help, but unfortunately, I think it's a problem with the project itself and not a WebSphere issue. Thanks for the help though!